# The UIViewControllerContextTransitioning won't give me a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing an incomprehensible problem I have a CollectionViewController and I want to make a custom animation. 
My collection is a gallery and I want to switch from collection gallery. to fullscreen gallery.

So I have ControllerTransitionDelegate

```
extension NavigationGalleryViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    return DimmingPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
}

func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    guard let selectedCellFrame = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))?.frame else { return nil }
    return PresentingAnimator(pageIndex: index, originFrame: selectedCellFrame)
}
```

My DimmingPresentationController

```
class DimmingPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

lazy var background = UIView(frame: .zero)

override var shouldRemovePresentersView: Bool {
    return false
}
override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
    setupBackground()
    // Grabing the coordinator responsible for the presentation so that the background can be animated at the same rate
    if let coordinator = presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator {
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
            self.background.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
    private func setupBackground() {
    background.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    background.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    background.frame = containerView!.bounds
    containerView!.insertSubview(background, at: 0)
    background.alpha = 0
}

}
```

And my presenting animator

```
class PresentingAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

private let indexPath: IndexPath
private let originFrame: CGRect
private let duration: TimeInterval = 0.5

init(pageIndex: Int, originFrame: CGRect) {
    self.indexPath = IndexPath(item: pageIndex, section: 0)
    self.originFrame = originFrame
    super.init()
}

func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return duration
}

func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to),
        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as? NavigationGalleryViewController, // The problem is here ! 
        let fromView = fromVC.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? InstallationViewCell
        else {
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            return
    }

 // All the animation things
 }
```

My BIG problem is that my execution go inside the else because he can't find the FromVC from the transitionContext.viewController. 
And here is how I call my Gallery

```
gallery = SwiftPhotoGallery(delegate: self, dataSource: self)

    // Gallery visual colours stuff
    gallery.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    gallery.transitioningDelegate = self

    present(gallery, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        self.gallery.currentPage = self.index
    })
}
```

This is what I receive from the transitionContext :

[image: Return]

Why the transitionContext won't give me the right VC ?

Comment: What kind of thing do you actually get from `transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)`?

Comment: I just updated with the image of that ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I checked and noticed that `transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)` is NavigationController.

In line: let `fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as? NavigationGalleryViewController` should be nil, because it is not NavigationGalleryViewController but NavigationController.

If you want you can make smth like this: `let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from).childViewControllers.first as? NavigationGalleryViewController`

Comment: But how is that a safe gamble? How is it happening? Why can't we get the proper view controller?